# How to add single quotes around the data-setup value that contains a JSON string that must use double quotes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code that creates elements and I can even add more attributes, classes, id among others

```
    if(is_video){
        Mcontent = $(document.createElement("video"))
        Msource = $(document.createElement("source"))
        Msource.attr("src",url)
        Msource.attr("type","video/"+formato)
        Mcontent.attr("class","video-js vjs-default-skin")
        Mcontent.append(Msource)
    }
```

Using the following code, I add attributes to a specific tag:

```js
var json = {"aspectRatio":"640:267", "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2]};
const content = $('video').addClass('video-js vjs-default-skin')
content.attr('data-setup', JSON.stringify(json));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video></video>
```

This gives me the following result when I inspect the code with the browser's developer tool:

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" data-setup="{"aspectRatio":"640:267","playbackRates":[1,1.5,2]}">

</video>
```

I need the attribute `data-setup=''` this with single quotes and not with double quotes `data-setup=""`, how can I get this result:

```
<video class="video-js" data-setup='{"aspectRatio":"640:267","playbackRates":[1,1.5,2]}'>

</video>
```

Observe the note of the [official documentation videoJS](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-setup.html). which warns: ***Note: You must use single-quotes around the value of data-setup as it contains a JSON string which must use double quotes.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pollute your HTML with single-quotes. JavaScript will encode the attribute value correctly for you....

```js
const Mcontent = $('video').addClass('video-js vjs-default-skin')
Mcontent.attr('data-setup', JSON.stringify({
  aspectRatio: "640:267",
  playbackRates: [1, 1.5, 2]
}))

// this is what the generated HTML will look like
$('pre').text($('section').html())

// decode example, just showing that it's possible
console.info(JSON.parse($('video').attr('data-setup')))
```

```css
section { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
<video></video>
</section>
<pre></pre>
```

The HTML-encoded value, ie

```html
<video data-setup="{&quot;aspectRatio&quot;:&quot;640:267&quot;,&quot;playbackRates&quot;:[1,1.5,2]}">
```

will be perfectly readable as JSON (assuming that's what is used for).

Here's an example of the generated markup ~ [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/philbrown/6efzbg8j/)

Comment: Using `data()` to get it from attributes will even return it parsed too

Comment: Excellent point. That's really up to this _videoJS_ plugin though

Comment: @Lou you do **not** need to generate the code with single-quotes. I've even provided examples

Comment: @Phil [Testing](https://jsfiddle.net/170cbvLs/) [result in image](https://i.imgur.com/OunquRQ.png). Was needed only single quotes in wrapping string of "data-setup" attribute. in this manner `data-setup='{code json}'`

Comment: @Lou the DOM inspector in your browser automatically decodes values for easier reading. The example in my answer above shows what the markup actually looks like

Comment: @Phil does not work for me :( this is not valid `<video data-setup="{&quot;aspectRatio&quot;:&quot;640:267&quot;,&quot;playbackRates&quot;:[1,1.5,2]}">` this way if `<video data-setup='{&quot;aspectRatio&quot;:&quot;640:267&quot;,&quot;playbackRates&quot;:[1,1.5,2]}'>`. observe the note of the [official documentation](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-setup.html). which warns: ***Note: You must use single-quotes around the value of data-setup as it contains a JSON string which must use double quotes.***

Comment: @Lou have you actually tried it? It seems to work just fine in the JSFiddle link in my answer

Comment: @Phil If friend, better I will continue practicing with the examples, the edition of the question will help as a reference for future readers who have a problem similar to mine.